# Third Party Software - where do we draw the line on 'on topic'?

Tags: discussion, scope

The Question was:

I need to use the Creative Cloud for Photoshop, Illustrator, etc for work so I'd like to install a very minimal windows 10, in Ubuntu VirtualBox, so I can run just what's necessary so Photoshop can run as fast as possible.

[What's the best way to install a very minimal Windows 10 as a Virtual Machine to run photoshop in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214611/whats-the-best-way-to-install-a-very-minimal-windows-10-as-a-virtual-machine-to?noredirect=1#comment2041581_1214611)

This question was closed as being off-topic.

I understand that topic of this question concerns third party software. Help Center > Asking states: Questions that you may ask include: Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.

Not only is VirtualBox third party software but when Windows is running in VirtualBox it is also, by definition, third party software.

Similar questions about running Photoshop in VirtualBox have been asked many times in Ask Ubuntu without being flagged off-topic. https://askubuntu.com/search?q=photoshop+virtualbox

I have not seen one that I consider an exact duplicate.

Google Says:

Third Party are ALL software that does not come normally recommended (100% free software) with Ubuntu in the CD/DVD. For example the Flash and MP3 are proprietary (Until a better software emerges which i have high hopes like Lightspark and Gnash).

My question is: Is this question off-topic.

Comment: @Thomas Ward : I asked this question in superUser, https://superuser.com/questions/1530451/whats-the-best-way-to-install-a-very-minimal-windows-10-as-a-virtual-machine-to?noredirect=1#comment2321378_1530451 and have received a few comments. So far no one has proposed a Tweak to the Windows OS that will make Photoshop run faster in Ubuntu VBox. Suggestions include Tweaks to Ubuntu, Vbox and Hardware, there is a link to making Windows smaller and less power hungry but not faster. The basic intent of the question is still to make Photoshop run faster in Ubuntu. That is what the Op needs.

Answer (score 6):

> Not only is VirtualBox third party software but when Windows is running in VirtualBox it is also, by definition, third party software.

True but that would mean EVERY question you can ask in http://superuser.com/ would be on topic as long as you include "virtual box" to the question. That is stretching it.

Installing virtualbox, installing tools for Virtualbox, how to set up Vbox is on topic.

Installing an OS inside virtualbox generally is not. That requires knowledge about that specific OS we so not need to have. The same goes for the software inside a vbox. As soon as virtualbox does no longer matter for the question asked it is off topic unless it is about Ubuntu (so a question about Ubuntu inside a vbox is on topic).

> Similar questions about running Photoshop in VirtualBox have been asked many times in Ask Ubuntu without being flagged off-topic. https://askubuntu.com/search?q=photoshop+virtualbox

Sort from newest and you will see that almost all are about WINE. Not Vbox. And those about vbox are mostly asking about how to install vbox and are using photoshop as an example of what they want to do. I have yet to find a topic similar to yours.

Comment: A person basically installs Photoshop in Windows, any tweeks are to Photoshop not Windows. When running Photoshop in Windows on VBox, there may be some tweeks to Photoshop and certainly tweeks to VBox such as installing Guest additions, Extension Packs, increasing Base Memory and Video Memory, enabling copy paste, 2D and 3D acceleration, specifying graphics controller, USB controller, (USB 3) and shared folders. and whether to install as Dynamically Allocated or Fixed Size. There is not a lot you can do to tweek the Windows OS on VBox. I do concede Windows questions should be on SU.

Comment: "any tweeks are to windows software" is the correct statement. And that is off topic

Comment: There are few or no tweaks to be made to Windows software running in VBox, that I know of to make it run faster. All tweaks to gain speed would be to Photoshop or VBox or hardware, If this is not your experience please explain.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron **except** that any tweaks inside the Guest OS in VBox (Photoshop or otherwise) at that point are not on topic here because that OS is then "Windows" that PS is running on.  Which makes it offtopic for *here*.

Comment: @Thomas Ward : I don't think you understand what I wrote. You can not tweak Windows, the Guest OS, in VBox to make it run Faster. Any tweak to make Photoshop run faster must be made to Photoshop, VBox, Ubuntu or the Computer Hardware, not to Windows, There is no secret Run Faster button in Windows. If you now how to Tweak the Windows OS to make it run faster, please give us an example. Millions of people would be thrilled. The only tweak I know is to just install one program in Windows.

Comment: If Photoshop is inside the Windows VM, then, that is a Windows-environment question.  Tweaks to the hardware or Ubuntu are on topic but not in the context of a Photoshop-inside-Windows-VM scope.

Comment: @Thomas Ward : By the same logic, if the Windows VM is inside Ubuntu VirtualBox then that is a Ubuntu-environment question. Photoshop only runs faster because Windows VM runs faster.

Comment: @Thomas Ward : My answer to the original question posted at Superuser. As you can see it looks out of place there. https://superuser.com/questions/1530451/whats-the-best-way-to-install-a-very-minimal-windows-10-as-a-virtual-machine-to/1530798#1530798

Comment: @C.S.Cameron your answer would have looked out of place at AskUbuntu either because the question is too broad and the answer is too generic.

Answer (score 3):

Asking about setting up VirtualBox on Ubuntu to install Windows (or any other OS) is completely on-topic.

However, asking about installing Photoshop on the Windows VM would be off-topic. As this requires Windows knowledge in order to properly set it up.

Finally, troubleshooting the Windows VM setup is sort of on the edge. You might face some VirtualBox issues which require modifications that need to be done on Ubuntu (on-topic) but it can also modifications that need to be done inside of the Windows installation (off-topic).

Comment: @C.S.Cameron lol it's not a big deal. Voting on meta is different any way. You should downvote if you disagree with a post. And upvote if you agree with it.

Comment: Dan is correct on that. Oh and my answer is not that different than the one from Dan. I wasted for more words to basically say the same :D

Comment: How do I vote if I agree with two thirds of it? Just because I do not agree with it completely does not mean that I think it is wrong. I do not think that the question is about installing Photoshop on the Windows VM, I think it is about tweaking VBox or Photoshop. I do not know of a way to tweak Windows to make it run faster in VBox, I do not know how to tweak the Windows OS to run faster on my desktop except to only run one app.